# precision and recall error while using sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, precision-recall

I am using sklearn precision and recall to get those scores. I got an error saying value error. Could anyone tell where am I doing wrong?

My y_test is as follows

```
443     positive
3615    positive
2030    negative
2993    positive
2870    positive
2907    negative
2215    positive
```

My Prediction is as follows

```
['positive' 'positive' 'positive' ..., 'positive' 'positive' 'positive']
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
precision_score(y_test, pred)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: pos_label=None is not a valid label: array(['negative', 'positive'], 
      dtype='<U8')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precision is defined as ratio of true positives to total predicted positives.

```
precision = tp / (tp + fp)
```

Now in your case, the program dont know which label is to be considered as positive class. So you need to define it yourself. Do this:

```
precision_score(y_test, pred, pos_label='positive')
```

Also, the error you shown: `pos_label=None is not a valid label` tells that you may have a older version of scikit. Newer versions should throw this error (if `pos_label` not specified):

```
pos_label=1 is not a valid label
```

So I would advice you to upgrade to latest version